# Push all contents of Stack to another stack?

Tags: vb.net, stack

I would like to Push all contents of say 'stackA' to 'stackB' in a single button click all at the same time.

Thanks

If you need additional info, please ask...

**Additional:**

I want to search for an item pushing 'stackA' Value into 'stackTemp' and Peek at 'stackTemp', which then puts the Peek value into a string. If the String equals the Value i searched for, then Show message Box with String and Pop all values from stackTemp into stackA. Otherwise keep Popping until the String matches the searched value.

**Pseudocode:**

Begin
    stackTemp.Push(stackA.Pop)
    strSearch <- stackTemp.Peek

```
If lblSearch.Text = txtSearch.Text then
        MsgBox(stackTemp.Pop)
        stackA.Push(stackTemp.Pop(All Items))
    Else
        'Do Nothing
    End If
```

End

Hope that Helps better

Comment: Actually now im not sure what you are asking, can you write it in pseudo-code? Or if you post the code you have, maybe it will be cleared

Comment: I updated my answer with a complete example of pushing a stack

Comment: Added pseudocode for you above

Comment: Still not sure what you are doing (the code is a bit malformatted) Is this correct: You want to loop through a stack, and if you find the element the rest of the elements should be pushed into another stack? Whats in the stacks?

Comment: In the stacks are 'License Plates', and yes thats correct

Comment: in not sure if im following your pseudocode, you can try my updated example

Answer (score 1):

Full working example of pushing a stack to another:

```
    'new stacks
    Dim stackA As New Stack(Of String)
    Dim stackB As New Stack(Of String)
    For n As Integer = 0 To 10
        stackA.Push("A" & n)
        stackB.Push("B" & n)
    Next

    'loop and push
    For Each item As String In stackA
        stackB.Push(item)
    Next

    'write the contents to console
    For Each item As String In stackB
        Console.WriteLine(item)
    Next
```

It loops over the items in stackA and pushes them to stackB. [Here is the documentation for this kind of loop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ebk1751.aspx)

You can replace the line   `stackA.Push(stackTemp.Pop(All Items))` in your pseudocode with:

```
       'loop and push
        For Each item As String In stackTemp
            stackA.Push(item)
        Next
```

Comment: iterate? sorry im new to stacks

Comment: Sorry it is not working. please check updated question for more info on what i am trying to achieve @zedd